# How to use Yahoo Contacts API in .net?

Tags: yahoo

I need to retrieve yahoo contacts using the Yahoo Contacts API. They have provided a PHP SDK but I have to implement it in ASP.NET. Can anybody assist me on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SocialAuth.NET` or go through its code for fetching contacts from Yahoo in `YahooWrapper.cs`

Answer (score -1):

You can access it via [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) - this is a webservice, so you can simply access it as such.